# Activate a second wordpress-installation on a domain

Tags: wordpress, installation

I have installed wordpress on a domain and I'm gonna add a second language so I've also installed another wordpress in a subdirectory. Now it's located in:

mysite.com/en/wordpress

but i need it to be

mysite.com/en

For the first installation i followed this guide:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

But it seems like it doesn't work with multisites.... So do I fix this?

Comment: Where are you up to? Have you had a go and run into an error?

Comment: Everything is installed and it looks good at mysite.com/en/wordpress. But i want it to be at mysite.com/en without the wordpress folder. That's the problem that I have..

Comment: Anyone? Maybe I should have installed it directly at mysite.com/en instead of mysite.com/en/wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

No it's no problem to change it. A few steps to follow.

Go into your WordPress admin panel and update the site url and blog url  to point to your new location. Then click save.

Rename the folder from wordpress to en

Finally you may have some problems with images, if so you will need to replace the old urls in your database. Personally I would import the database, run a find and replace and then re-import the sql script.

Here is another solution though that runs a query on the database and will also work. http://www.master-script.com/moving-wordpress-site-to-new-domain.html

**Note** if you are going to run the find and replace on the database anyway the first step is irrelevant as it will be changed also.